Why is it called Camelot wheel? Why Camelot?
I read on https://dj.studio/blog/camelot-wheel:

The Camelot Wheel is a modern system to help DJs navigate the musical keys of their music.
It's based on the circle of fifths, with the only difference being the use of additional labels instead of using the original key names. This aims to make it easier for DJs to understand.

Why is it called Camelot wheel? Why Camelot?

Wild guess: Comes from the Arthurian "Round Table".

I contacted Mixed In Key, but they don't know the name's origin. I guess you'd have to track down Mark Davis (the inventor) to ask.

@Aaron Got it, thanks for contacting them!

The more burning question for me is "Was it really so hard to learn the names of the notes and the words 'major' and 'minor'?"

@Edward it seems to me that the name of a music-theoretical tool is on topic regardless of the reasoning behind the name -- especially since one may not know until reading the answer whether the reason has anything to do with music theory.

@Theodore probably not, but a DJ without the context of an education in music theory will have a harder time of it, and a harder time still of remembering the order ..., B flat, F, C, G, D, A, E, B, F sharp, ....  It's rather arbitrary.

@Aaron I'd promote that to a full answer, since I can't see that anything more definitive can be found online. Plenty of Arthurian speculation, but "we don't know" is the only real answer for now.

@phoog You're right that learning the sequence of the circle of fifths is initially more difficult than the Camelot system, and it might seem arbitrary at first (of course it isn't really arbitrary at all).  Learning traditional note names & qualities does open you up to understanding the key of music that hasn't already been classified under Camelot.  (OT, but worth noting that Camelot is totally blind to modulations.)

@Theodore Which is odd, because the provided link talks about how you can switch "moods" - between major and minor of the same letter name - but the Camelot Wheel doesn't make it easy to tell which ones those are, so you still need to know the traditional names on top of the Camelot numbers

@Aaron In the interview with Mark Davis on the Mixed in Key site, he says that he originally called it the "Easymix system", so the Camelot name came later!

The round table of Camelot is often illustrated as divided into segments:

(Source: Wikimedia Commons)
As such, it does look superficially like the circle of fifths.

Uh, superficially indeed. Unless I miscount that's 25 segments (counting Arthur, King of the Britons).

@AndyBonner Well, after all, it's only a model.

The round table also looks like a roullette wheel, but I guess that term was already taken.

@Barmar Good thing they didn't arrange they keys in the bizarre sequence used in roulette! (0-32-15-19-4-21-2-25-17-34-6-27-13-36-11-30-8-23-10-5-24-16-33-1-20-14-31-9-22-18-29-7-28-12-35-3-26)

I contacted Mixed In Key, but they didn't know the name's origin. I also did not find anything online that suggested an origin. An interview with Mark Davis, the inventor, discusses the origins of the wheel itself, but not the name. This leaves tracking down Mark Davis and asking him directly; however, I did not find contact information.

Another question to ask Mark Davis is why 1A/1B is not aligned with G Major / E Minor so at least people start associating 1-6 with the number of sharps so they can transition to proper circle of fifths.

I believe it's just a brand name (or a product name, by Mixed In Key), and the name became genericized (like kleenex) to signify the concept.

The question is why "Camelot" was chosen as the name.

Aaron - yes, but you'd probably have to ask a marketing person at Mixed In Key to find the answer, which is probably "I think it will sell".
